# For loop triggered by addEventListener click (JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger 'for loop' by clicking, with 'addEventListener' function.
I've seen lots of questions asking how to make addEventListener embedded in for loop, but couldn't find a case of the opposite, for loop embedded in addEventListener.

This is the html
-----html-----

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <p id="myP">HO HO HO</p>
</div>
```

-----JavaScript-----

```
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    var objs = {Aman : function(){myDiv.style.background="yellow"}, 
                Bman : function(){myDiv.style.margin = "30px"},
                Cman : function(){myDiv.style.border ="blue"}};

    function loop(){
      for(var i=0; i < objs.length ; i++){
          return objs[Object.keys(objs)[i]] }
                   };

    myDiv.addEventListener("click", loop);
```

I really can't find why this doesn't work.
Really appreciate for you genius.

p.s;
 If this can't work, then how can I link more than one events to just one 'addEventListener' phrase?

Comment: The condition `for(var i=0; i < objs.length ; i++){` is incorrect. You can get the `Object` length using `Object.keys.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems.
1. At for loop you use `objs.length` but there is no length of an object.
2. Into the objs you define functions. But you don't call the functions.

You can check this out. It may help you.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

var objs = {
  Aman: function() {
    myDiv.style.background = "yellow";
  },
  Bman: function() {
    myDiv.style.margin = "30px";
  },
  Cman: function() {
    myDiv.style.border = "blue";
  }
};

function loop() {
  // loop through Object.keys(objs).length not objs.length
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(objs).length; i++) {
    objs[Object.keys(objs)[i]](); // You have to call the function
  }
}

myDiv.addEventListener("click", loop);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p id="myP">HO HO HO</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through properties of your object.

```js
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    var objs = {
      Aman: function() {
        myDiv.style.background = "yellow";
      },
      Bman: function() {
        myDiv.style.margin = "30px";
      },
      Cman: function() {
        myDiv.style.border = "blue";
      }
    };
    function loop() {
      for (var key of Object.keys(objs)) {
        objs[key]();
      }
    }

    myDiv.addEventListener("click", loop);
```

```html
    <div id="myDiv">
      <p id="myP">HO HO HO</p>
    </div>
```